# Memory allocation of a structure in C

Tags: c, memory-management, struct

I am designing a small game in C with `libX11` and `libpthread` on Linux platform, and all level information is filled into a struct array `Level[Level_Amount]`.

```
struct Pos
{ 
   int X; 
   int Y; 
};

struct Pos_Info
{ 
   int Flag; 
   int Drctn; 
   int Layer; 
   struct Pos Postn; 
   int Color; 
};

struct In_Out_Chnl
{ 
   struct Pos Drctn[Channel_Amount]; 
};

struct Check_Point
{ 
   int Remain; 
   struct Pos Postn[Chk_Pnt_Amount]; 
};

struct Level_Info
{ 
   char Map[Rbn_Col][Rbn_Row]; 
   struct Pos_Info Draw, Rcvd;
   struct Check_Point Chk_Pnt; 
   struct In_Out_Chnl Channel; 
};

struct Level_Info Level[Level_Amount];
```

I am confused whether it is a good way to read and write the struct array from a file as below:

```
FILE *fp;
fwrite(&Level, sizeof(struct Level_Info), Level_Amount, fp);
fread (&Level, sizeof(struct Level_Info), Level_Amount, fp);
```

Will the memory allocation of a struct (with different type of elements) differ from compilers or CPU ?

Is there a better way to save and read the whole struct **safely**?

Comment: search the web for data serialization

Comment: Yes, that may differ. You should have your own method to read/write structures one field at a time. That's one of the typical situations where having an OO language might help.

Comment: serialization is non-trivial problem, try some already implemented solution such as http://troydhanson.github.io/tpl/index.html

Comment: @petrbel Thanks. I visited the website, and currently tpl does not support fixed-length array suffixes on inner structures. I think I should do everything from scratch all by myself. :-)

Comment: Your question is *not* related to memory allocation (e.g. `malloc`), and you don't tell us what e.g. `Channel_Amount` is. I believe that [libsdl](https://www.libsdl.org/), [JSON](http://json.org/) -with [Jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) library- and [flexible array members](http://d3s.mff.cuni.cz/~holub/c_features.html) could be useful to you.

Comment: Please **edit your question to improve it**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the way you suggest, but keep in mind that you then need to stick to the struct layout you have. This means

- you cannot change array dimension
- you cannot add or remove data members
- you cannot have pointers or pointer like data in the structs (you don't seem to have so)
- an int in the file must be the same size as an int in memory (can't work cross platform so easily)
- an int in the file must have the same byte order as an int in memory (can't work cross platform so easily)

Regarding the int issues you can include `stdint.h` and use types like `int32_t`. For the byte order you could keep the data in the file in network byte order and then use the socket conversion functions `ntohs` and `ntohl` for byte order conversion.

And always keep in mind: if you read from a file, you are dealing with external input, so be prepared that the input is total garbage (attacker might have changed it).

You might also want to Google the term `serialization` which is the process or writing data from memory to a persistent storage and retrieving it back again.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, but be aware of the following:

- Under different optimisation levels (or compilers) the structs will be represented or packed differently. You should use structure packing intrinsics to handle this. See here:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx
  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html
- Your structs cannot have members with pointers inside them. If they do, the pointers must be relative offsets to memory which is held inside i.e. an arena. The reason for this is what when you `fread` them back from the file, everything will be in a completely different location in memory so the pointers will be invalidated.

Additionally, I recommend that you use memory mapping -- it tends to not only give higher performance, but with some operating-system-specific code you can teach it to grow the file automatically as your structures get bigger;

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file